# Why one cannot instantiate iterator this way?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

First, have a look at this code.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
> undefined
var si1 = arr[Symbol.iterator];
> undefined
var it1 = si1();
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object(…)(anonymous function) @ VM11886:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM9769:875InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM9769:808InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM9769:664
var it2 = arr[Symbol.iterator]();
> undefined
it2.next()
> Object {value: 1, done: false}
```

And now the question: why the type error is produced? Is the way I call `it1` not the same (or equivalent) to the way I call `it2`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call it as `si1()`, the function has a `this` of `undefined`. `arr[Symbol.iterator]()` sets `this` to `arr`.

Considering that

```
arr[Symbol.iterator] === Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator]
```

it has to be that the context when the function is called is what determines the result.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ryan O'Hara's answer, you can bind iterator to the correct context:

```
var si1 = arr[Symbol.iterator].bind(arr);
var it1 = si1();
it1.next();
```